# Python: Split list in to sets

Tags: python, set, iterable, enumerate

I'm trying to split a list in to enumerated sets and I have a implementation that seems to do what I want but it doesn't feel very "pythonic" is there a better way?

The below example splits the item in to sets of maximum size 3 and returns each item from items along with a set number and set index

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def SplitSets(iterable,set_size):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for elem in iterable:
        yield row, col, elem
        if col == set_size - 1:
            row = row+1
        col = (col + 1) % set_size

for a,b,c in SplitSets(items,3):
    print a,b,c
```

Expected output is

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Comment: Can you tell us what output you wanted? Your question is rather unclear, as it stands.

Comment: You are not producing `set` objects, which is what most Python developers would expect you to be referring to when you use that term. Are you trying to group your list into chunks?

Comment: Martijn, Correct, poor usage of terminology on my behalf. I'm trying to sort a list of items in groups with a maximum size of a specified number. Use Case being that I want to have a list of buttons that will be sorted in to x number of rows with a maximum number in each row

Comment: It sounds like you just want the `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` docs. In which case... Just copy that recipe, or install `more_itertools` and import it from there. And if that's what you want, it's almost certainly a dup, unless you think enumerating the outer and inner iterables is the hard part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not much to explain, only the division and module is used to find the row and column number

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  

def SplitSets(iterable,set_size): 
  #return a generator
  return ((i/set_size, i%set_size,e) for i,e in enumerate(iterable))

for a,b,c in SplitSets(items,3):
  print a,b,c
```

a similar code is:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def SplitSets(iterable,set_size):
    for i, elem in enumerate(iterable):
        yield i/set_size, i%set_size, elem

for a,b,c in SplitSets(items,3):
    print a,b,c
```

Comment: probably change 3 to set_size

Comment: OP's code creates a generator. Maybe you should also change it to `return ((i/...ble))`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use itertools:

```
from itertools import count, cycle, izip

def split_sets(iterable, set_size):
    for a, b, c in izip(count(), cycle(range(set_size)), items):
        yield a // set_size, b, c

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
set_size = 3
for a, b, c in split_sets(items, set_size):
    print a, b, c
```

## Discussion

- For the first column (a), we call on `count()`, which returns *0, 1, 2, 3, 4...* We then integer divide a with the set_size to get what we want
- For the second column, `range(set_size)` returns *[0, 1, 2]* for set_size of 3. The `cycle()` function then repeat this sequence over and over.
- No explanation needed for the last column
- Now, if we take these columns and `izip` (which is more efficent than zip for Python 2.x) together, we will get what we want.